# Select distinct after "removing" trailing spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is a column ID (varchar) which has repeated values. Some of these values have trailing spaces which I don't want to see when i do a select.

I want to do a "select distinct after removing trailing spaces".

I tried the code below and it does not help. I still get trailing spaces in output.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TRIM(@string VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@string))
END
GO
SELECT dbo.TRIM(' String ')
GO
```

then,

```
select distinct dbo.trim(MyID) as Trimmed
from dbo.SourceTbl
```

Code taken from - 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/01/23/sql-server-trim-function-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-spaces-of-string-sql-in-sixty-seconds-040-video/

Comment: Seems to work for me. What are your values in `MyID`?

Comment: Where do you see the trailing spaces?

Comment: Are the characters that are being rendered as "spaces" actually spaces and not some other whitespace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this, maybe?

```
SELECT DISTINCT trimmed
FROM (
    SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(MyID)) as trimmed
    FROM dbo.SourceTbl
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Distinct  replace(Colum, ' ', '') AS Trimmed
FROM Table

DECLARE @String1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @String1 = ' String '
SELECT @String1 OriginalString, RTRIM(LTRIM(@String1)) TrimmedValue
GO
```

To create a function to remove leading and trailing spaces

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TRIM(@string VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@string))
END
GO


SELECT DISTINCT dbo.TRIM(' String ')
GO
```

Comment: this function will remove any white spaces in a string and the you can Select Distinct values from white space free values/column. :)

Comment: [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(computers)) includes spaces, tabs, ..., whereas this code only handles spaces.  It is also unclear why you use a loop around `REPLACE()` when it will replace all occurrences in a single call.  This also replaces spaces within a string, though the OP requested a means to remove trailing (and possibly leading) spaces.  How is this an improvement over mbomb's earlier answer?

Comment: Opsss I have just notice now after you mentioned I really dont need a while loop here. REPLACE() function do replace all the white spaces in single occurrence. I dont know why but I thought it will replace very 1st white space in case of multiple white spaces. in this case we dont even need a udf.

Comment: It removes all spaces. I need only leading and trailing spaces, tabs, blank removed.